# Consume Web Service XML - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I'm trying to consume a xml but I'm getting NullPointerException in line:

```
  InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent();
```

There's my consume method and you can check the xml in url

```
public class XMLDownloader {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://proapaplicativos.com.br/jccuritiba/listarEventos.php");
    HttpResponse res = null;
    NodeList result = null;
   // Thread t = new Thread();

    public NodeList GetNodeList() throws InterruptedException{   
        //String url = "http://fiscalartesp.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc/login?";

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    res = client.execute(method);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    URL urls;
                    urls = new URL("http://proapaplicativos.com.br/jccuritiba/listarEventos.php");
                    InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent();
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(urls.openStream()));
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    result = doc.getElementsByTagName("Evento");                         
                    is.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                     Log.i("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }     

            }
        }).start();
        /*
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

        }).start();
        */
        while(result == null)
        {
            //Log.i("Aguardando", "Aguardando resposta");
        }


        return result;              
    }
}
```

Comment: there are several things conserning me, `res=client.execute(method);` => if this fails you still going to use `res` later on??? So you should test what is `null`, is it `res` or is it `res.getContent()`.  These are the first steps what you need to do.

Comment: How can I do then to use `res` only after `client.execute(method)` response?

Comment: It should all be in the first `try/ catch` or set res `null` in the `catch` and check for `null` later. (I do prefer all the code in the first `try/catch`)

Comment: but I'm already using try/catch...and catch the NullPointerException..but I need the response...only get the exception doesn't help me

Comment: @chillworld if I got `catch` how could I do to check again and again until response is not null?

Comment: a loop, but be carefull. Is looping what you want if the network is down?

Comment: @chillword the web service never respond. But the web service is ok. Look at http://proapaplicativos.com.br/jccuritiba/ListarEventos.php